# gnome-terminal not working over X11 (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: unity, gnome, xorg, gnome-terminal, x11-forwarding

I have two Ubuntu 14.04 servers, both with SSHD and X11 forwarding properly set up: most X11 apps work correctly when I connect with my XServer (MobaXterm 9.4 from Windows).  For example, these correctly run: `xterm`, `gedit`, `pgadmin3`, and my PyQt applets.

However, I can't get `gnome-terminal` to work.  It just silently dies without opening a window or giving any error message.  Same behavior on both hosts; same behavior in foreground or background.

How do I debug this?  Is there a log file somewhere, or a debug option I can turn on?

Possible workaround: I find that `lxterminal` works well from my Raspberry Pi to MobaXterm.  I would consider installing that on my Gnome/Unity-based Ubuntu boxes just to use it as my remote terminal.  But how much of LXDE would I need to pull in to do *that*... and would I cause other trouble/break other GTK stuff?

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect what you're bumping up against is this: [Run true multiple process instances of gnome-terminal](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/201915/65304)

Comment: Stumbling across my own questions YEARS later.  I think I recall what was going on was this: I running additional gnome-terminals was causing terminals to pop up on the "actual" gnome-desktop, rather than on my (Windows-based) XServer.  Err, well, maybe.  It was a long time ago!

Answer (score 1):

I am using lxterminal since many years. It belongs to LXDE (which is the desktop environment of Lubuntu). I checked quickly in a live system of standard Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. You have two choices, to install with or without the recommended packages.

```
sudo apt-get install lxterminal
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends lxterminal
```

With and without the recommended packages it will add 2.5 MB to standard Ubuntu. I think things will continue to work :-)